# IE 8 CSS hover over input element issue

Tags: html, css, input, hover, submit

My Issue:

The code below works for me in FireFox and Google Chrome, but in IE the button does not change colors. could someone show me how I can fix this issue. Any Suggestions?
My input element:

```
<input id="pmunch" type="submit" value="Post It!"/>
```

The CSS relevant to this element:

```
#pmunch{
width:240px;
height:28px;
padding:2px 4px;
margin-left:24px;
font-family:‘Lucida Console’, Monaco, monospace;
font-size:18px;
border:none;
float:left;
background-color:turquoise;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
}
#pmunch:hover{
background-color:khaki;
color:green;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: I don't think IE likes the `:hover` pseudo-class on anything other than `<a>` tags

Comment: @Shad: You are correct. But the OP really needs to describe the error more.

Comment: IE6 doesn't like it.  IE8 doesn't mind it at all, last i tried it.

Comment: @Shad: Any version of IE greater than 6 is fine with `:hover` on other elements.

Comment: I described the issue I am sorry!

Comment: Works in IE8 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NyrBL/ - could you provide your entire HTML file? (you can remove irrelevant stuff if you like, but make sure the issue is still there..)

Comment: I am using IE8. It must have to do with the context I have this code in, because The code worked in thirtydot's jsfiddle for me but not on my website.

Comment: Like I said in my last comment, we need more informationz! Without it, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @inquisitive: **What** context? What's **your** code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing i've noticed is that if the browser is in quirks mode (ie: if you don't have a doctype line at the top of the page), IE -- even IE8 -- doesn't like :hover on anything but links.

Even `<!DOCTYPE html>` is enough to trigger standards mode.  Add that if it isn't already there.

Comment: A likely candidate. I suspect this is the problem, but I was hoping he'd post his code so I could be sure. Oh well.

Comment: That was it Thanks! And thank you everyone else for helping me out to.