# :hover does not seem to be working on custom buttons

Tags: css, hover

I have a couple custom buttons that are working and look fine, except the hover stopped working (should change color on hover.  It worked when I first coded but at some point it stopped.  I am not sure when it stopped, or why. It is not working in either chrome, firefox or IE8.  Obviously I have messed something up but I have yet to find it.  I will keep looking and researching, but if you have any ideas, much appreciated.

html:

```
<input class="left-menu-button" type="button" value="Search" />
<input class="left-menu-button" type="button" value="View Detail" />
```

css:

```
.left-menu-button
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #631127;
    border: none;
    margin: 20px 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    float: right;
}

.left-menu-button:hover
 {
       background-color: #A3143A !important;
 }
```

Comment: [Works](http://jsfiddle.net/V82WW/) in Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: that should work - http://jsfiddle.net/WNMT9/  you probably have some other styles that take precedence over these

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/qcHSR/). Something else is wrong in your css. Maybe you are overriding with `input:hover` or something similar.

Comment: Interesting but makes sense, because it was working.  Ok I will search around.  Are there any 'common hover killers' or anything like that, that I should look for first (other than obvious inline stuff)?

Comment: nope - just look around your code in Firebug or Developer Tools.. it will show you all the applied styles of an element

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) Open your page in **Google Chrome**;
2) Press **F12** for "Developer Tools" to open;
3) Select your problematic input;
4) On the right you have the applied styles;
5) On the "**Styles**" tab, click on the **2nd icon**, a cursor inside a dotted rectangle;
6) Select **":hover"**, so that you can see what's happening when your input is being hovered and find the problem!

Comment: Thanks Ivozor, I was trying to figure out how to activate that control when I saw your answer.  I noticed that when I tried to 'Inspect Element' on one of the buttons, the developer window would open in a different div.  I eventually found that div had a 100% height, which I guess was hiding the buttons and causing the hover not to register.

Comment: This handy tip made me realize that another inline css was overwriting the hover state. I fixed it by adding !important to the hover class.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. I tried working with the developer tools in Chrome, but to no avail. In the end, it turned out that I needed to delete the extra space between the ID selector and the :hover attribute. For example,

```css
#button :hover {
  background-color: #7e7ecc;
}
```

The snippet above didn't work, but the snippet below did

```css
#button:hover {
  background-color: #7e7ecc;
}
```

The second I figured it out, I knew that's what had caused the issue, but in case someone else gets stuck, there you go

Comment: Insane!! and it's true!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it helps, i was having the same problem with this css; without anything else on the css, in a test page; junt only two css styles.

With the next css, hover did not work (see that `:hover` declaration is before `background-color` declaration):

```
button:hover{
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
}
button.myButton{
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

And i solved just by writting that css just in different order (see that now `:hover` declaration is after `background-color` declaration):

```
button.myButton{
  background-color:transparent;
}
button:hover{
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
}
```

This 'order' makes `:hover` to work again, so declaring `:hover` after `background-color` solved the problem.

Why on the hell does this 'order' affects?, i have no idea, it is not logical that declaration order could affect, but affects (at least on FireFox version 70.0.1); maybe it is a bad implementation on web-browsers !!!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone is having the same issue that I was having I'm going to post.

The solution for me was that the button that wouldn't show the :hover CSS had a custom background that was set via the element ID. I switched it to a class and was able to see the :hover styling after that. I guess ID background styling takes precedence over :hover styling set through the element tag name.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same issue...

Using a linear gradient on a "parent element" will block any color changes on :hover or :focus events using background-color or color. You will need to use background-image as well on the :hover and :focus events:

```
#grad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! To improve your answer, you could add a link to a source that confirms this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu-btn">
        <button class="item-btn"><img src="./icon/Badge Discount.svg" alt="Badge">Best seller</button>
        <button class="item-btn"><img src="./icon/Burger.svg" alt="Burger">Hamburger</button>
        <button class="item-btn"><img src="./icon/Cup 01.svg" alt="Cup">Drink</button>
        <button class="item-btn"><img src="./icon/Ice Cream.svg" alt="Cream">Dessert</button>
        <button class="item-btn"><img src="./icon/Serving Plate.svg" alt="Serving">Fried chicken</button>
</div>
```

> css code:

```
.menu-btn button {
border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
border-radius: 100px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-family: light;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 36px;
letter-spacing: 0em;
text-align: left;
color: #504F4F;
margin-right: 1.6rem;
}

.item-btn:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #FFC300;
border: 1px solid #FFD429;
}
```

with this code above, the hover didn't work. then i added position relative to the class menu-btn button, afterwards it worked well.

> code below:

```
.menu-btn button {
border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
border-radius: 100px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-family: light;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 36px;
letter-spacing: 0em;
text-align: left;
color: #504F4F;
margin-right: 1.6rem;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I too encountered the same situation, then I tried instead of using the class name for the `:hover` function, better use an "id". When i used it, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

This post may answer your question:
[IE 8 CSS hover over input element issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138481/ie-8-css-hover-over-input-element-issue)

The page might be forcing the browser into quirks mode.

Comment: it's not just an IE8 issue, so the answer is irrelevant