# Displaying some text when mouse is over an input text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an input text box, on which I would like to display some text area when the user's mouse get over it, giving to him informations on the text to enter. 
here is my HTML code :

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.mouseover 
{



}

</style>
<span onmouseover="this.classname='mouseover'" onmouseout="this.classename=''"></span>
<input id="mybox" type="text" />

</body>
</html>
```

What is the best CSS trick that would help to do that ?
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: css `:hover` have you tried?

Comment: Yes micnic :) I've tried the answer provided by @Midhum but it's not working on IE8 :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do all of this with CSS.  Play around with CSS triangles for the tooltip but what you're mainly looking for is to use the `:hover` pseudo-class.  No need for Javascript.

```
.input {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.input:hover .tooltip {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    bottom: -60px;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

.input:hover .tooltip:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/1/

Comment: Thanks @richieahb , This is what I was looking for :) But it's not working on IE8.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138481/ie-8-css-hover-over-input-element-issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery Tooltip:

[Jquery Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Answer (score 1):

Just one more way to do that...

[Filldle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CvtLq/)

For me in IE8 OK [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CvtLq/3/)

```
<input type="text">
<span>Some Text inside... </span>




span {
        background-color: rgba(0,102,255,.15);
        border: 2px solid rgba(0,102,255,.5);
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: #000;
        display: none;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

span:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    border-color:  transparent transparent rgba(0,102,255,.5) transparent;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    width: 0;
}

input {
    display: block
}

input:hover + span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px
}
```

Comment: @Sven.The above example is giving me tooltip for all the text fields..How can we get it for only a particular text field

Comment: Use classes instead of html elements as selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
* simple css-based tooltip */
.tooltip {
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;

    /* outline radius for mozilla/firefox only */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
}
 // select all desired input fields and attach tooltips to them
      $("#myform :input").tooltip({

      // place tooltip on the right edge
      position: "center right",

      // a little tweaking of the position
      offset: [-2, 10],

      // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
      effect: "fade",

      // custom opacity setting
      opacity: 0.7

      });
```

got to this link http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this property it's asp but may work for your case

***ErrorMessage="Your Message";***

Comment: where should I put this attribute @pakitoUser3205849 ?

Comment: Try in your input balise. Here under my case which works for me :  <td><asp:TextBox  ID="Mybox" MaxLength="4"</asp:TextBox></td>          <td>                                
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexTextBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Mybox" ErrorMessage="check field" />
                            </td>

Comment: What validation would you like for the text ? You have to write your validation in property ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{4}$" (^[0-9]{4}$) is an example for 4 digits) of the asp:RegularExpressionValidator Then after the error message would be display whether the text is valid or not.

Comment: I'm not on asp @pakito I'm using xhtml with jsp